# Could not attach to pid : “1588”

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have converted Cordova Android app into iOS using Xcode. When I typed "**cordova build ios**" on terminal it build successfully.

After that I have opened "**myApp.xcodeproj**" in xcode and clicked on Run but it's failed by given "**Could not attach to pid : “1588”**" this error. If anyone knows about this issue please suggest and also let me know how to run the app on iOS device.

I have installed MAC OS through VMware virtual machine.

Comment: Have you tried to run the project again?

Comment: Yes i have tried more than twice. simulator opened but when i click on myapp in that it given above error

Comment: And can anyone guide how to generate .ipa file for ios? Due to that above error i can't able to test my app on simulator itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the content and settings of your Simulator.

For doing that go to your simulator, in the top menu Click on Simulator > "Reset content and settings".
After that quit your Simulator. Re-run your App.

To run any app on an iOS device, connect the iOS device to your system, and you will be able to see your device as an option, amongst the other various simulators you see in Xcode. Right next to the run button.